# Newly installed credential plugin on Jenkins does not show type of credential 'secret text'

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I'm running the `jenkins/jenkins:lts` docker container and I just installed the `credential` plugin. Installation was successful however I could not create a credential of type "Secret Text". Here's what I see :

[image]

What could be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

The Credential plugin is the keystore.  The types of credential files offered in your drop list depends on what other plugins you have installed.  To have the *Secret Text* option, you need to install the [Plain Credentials Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Plain+Credentials+Plugin).  You will also need the [Credentials Binding Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Credentials+Binding+Plugin) installed to pass the credentials to build steps in a job.  You may want to read through the [Cloud Bees article](https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/203802500-Injecting-Secrets-into-Jenkins-Build-Jobs) regarding this plugin.